# Tuple index out of range? python 3.4.2

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

I am creating a csv file quiz in python, it is all fine up until I get to the summary at the end of the quiz.

```
percentage = (correctScore * 100) / 20

print("Alright now, lets see how you did... ")
time.sleep(2)
if correctScore == 20:
    print("Excellent work there, (yourNameIs), you scored 100%. ")
elif correctScore >= 11 <= 19:
    print("Well done", yourNameIs, "you passed. You scored", percentage,"%. You got {} question(s) wrong".format(len(incorrect)))
    for question, user_answer in incorrect:
        print("Q{}: {}".format(data[question][0]))
        print("\tYou answered {}. The correct answer is {}".format(user_answer, data[question][5]))
elif correctScore >= 5 <= 10:
    print("Good effort", yourNameIs, "you scored", percentage,"%. You got {} question(s) wrong".format(len(incorrect)))
    for question, user_answer in incorrect:
        print("Q{}: {}".format(data[question][0]))
        print("\tYou answered {}. The correct answer is {}".format(user_answer, data[question][5]))
else:
    print("You need to try harder next time", yourNameIs, "you scored", percentage,"%. You got {} question(s) wrong".format(len(incorrect)))
    for question, user_answer in incorrect:
        print("Q{}: {}".format(data[question][0]))
        print("\tYou answered {}. The correct answer is {}".format(user_answer, data[question][5]))
```

After I get my percentage, I get an error

```
print("Q{0}: {1}".format(data[question][0]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any ideas?

```
correctScore = 0 
incorrect = [] 
question = data[recordnum-1][0] 
a = data[recordnum-1][1] 
b = data[recordnum-1][2] 
c = data[recordnum-1][3] 
d = data[recordnum-1][4] 
answer = data[recordnum-1][5] –
```

Comment: 1. show us where `data` gets assigned please, and the code for that.
2. give me an example of the format of the input data. not just csv, but literally what one entry would look like

Comment: @Vincenzzochi Sorry. heres what i got correctScore = 0
    incorrect = []

    myFile = open("questions.csv","r") # opens the csv file and stores it in the array myFile
    lines = myFile.readlines() # reads the lines of the CSV file into the variable players
    recordnum=1

    random.shuffle(lines)
    data = [p.strip().split(",") for p in lines]

Comment: Is `question` also a number, or is it a string?

Comment: Wasnt meant to send that ^.                                                                                                  correctScore = 0
incorrect = []

        question = data[recordnum-1][0]
        a = data[recordnum-1][1]
        b = data[recordnum-1][2]
        c = data[recordnum-1][3]
        d = data[recordnum-1][4]
        answer = data[recordnum-1][5]

Comment: Include this code inside your question.

Comment: You're missing so much information on your question that it's pointless to try and figure out this mess.

Answer (score 1):

You  use two `{}` in the format string but only pass one arg, python expects two arguments to format so you get the `IndexError: tuple index out of range`:

```
print("Q{0}: {1}".format(data[question][0]))  
        ^^    ^^
```

If `data[question]` has two elements you can unpack with `*`:

```
print("Q{0}: {1}".format(*data[question]))
```

Either way you need to pass two args.